# DataFrame Column into multiple columns

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

Column
[image: Column]

How can I split a data frame column that contain list of strings like

```
[{'1','1','1','1'},{'1','1','1','1'},{'1','1','1','1'},{'1','1','1','1'}]
```

In each cell, into multiple columns of data frame?

Consider that the lists in each cell of the column are not with the same length!

In above image on the left we have the first column and on the right we are watching the results that I want to make.

Comment: The structure you are showing is a list of dicts that only contain keys.
a list of lists might be more reasonable e.g. [['1','1','1','1'],['1','1','1','1'], ... ].

Comment: For the var length problem. I would use len(sublist) to determine the total number of columns needed and create that many columns first.

Answer (score 0):

As @Oliver Prislan comments -- that is an unusual structure - did you mean something else? If your data is structured like that then here is a way you can get it into the new format:

```
# assumes that your original dataframe is called `df`
# creates a new dataframe called new_df
# removes the unwanted {} and [] and ''
# then expands the columns after splitting each string on the comma
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['Column0'].str.replace('[{}\[\]\']','').str.split(',', expand=True),
                index=df.index) 
 #renames the columns as you wanted them
new_df.rename(columns='col{}'.format, inplace=True)
```

If your values are always numeric and you may want to convert the dataframe columns to numeric datatypes:

```
for col in new_df.columns:
    new_df[col] = pd.to_numeric(new_df[col])
```

Final result:

```
 col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10  col11  col12  col13  col14  col15
0     1     1     1     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1     1     1     1     1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2     1     1     1     1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    1.0    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3     1     1     1     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4     1     1     1     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
5     1     1     1     1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```